# SQL to get rows with hightest value per month and over all months

Tags: sql, hana

I need some help writing SQL statement for below requirements(FINAL REULT).

note: I am writing this SQL on SAP HANA system(database) using SQL syntax. The SQL syntax is normal universally used.

**some abbreviations used for column names:**

```
cust = customer
ctry = country
mth = month
HCostPP = Highest cost per period
HCtryPP = highest country per period
HCostAP = Highest cost over all periods
HCtryAP = highest country over all periods
```

i have granular data in my source table. By writing SQL like below, i get aggregated data:

```
SELECT distinct cust,ctry,mth,sum(cost)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust,ctry,mth

I get aggregated data like which i used further to get my required results:  
cust  ctry  mth     cost
c001   US  201506  -100
c001   DK  201506  -100
c001   DE  201506  -50
c001   FR  201507  -200
c001   UK  201507   -50
```

**THE FINAL required RESULT** i want to achieve should look like below:

```
cust   ctry  mth   cost  HCostPP HCtryPP HCostAP HCtryAP
c001   US  201506  -100  -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   DK  201506  -100  -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   DE  201506  -50   -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   FR  201507  -200  -200    FR      -200    FR
c001   UK  201507   -50  -200    FR      -200    FR
```

**Explanation of required results**

```
based on data group (cust,ctry,mth) need to get for which 
country COST were hightest 'within each month' (HCostPP , HCtryPP)
and then again 'over all months'(HCostAP , HCtryAP).
```

**CATCH**

```
for month 201506, -100 cost is same for both US and DK. 
In this case take either one e.g. DK or US (i am showing above to take DK)
```

**WHAT I TRIED:**
i understand that two left joins are needed. first left join should look like below to get HCostPP , HCtryPP:

```
LEFT SIDE                            RIGHT SIDE
cust   ctry  mth   cost          cust   ctry  mth   cost
c001   US  201506  -100          c001   DK  201506  -100
c001   DK  201506  -100          c001   FR  201507  -200
c001   DE  201506  -50
c001   FR  201507  -200
c001   UK  201507   -50
```

in order to get RIGHT SIDE table, when i write SQL like:

```
SELECT cust,ctry,mth, MIN(cost)
FROM
(
SELECT distinct cust,ctry,mth,sum(cost)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust,ctry,mth
)
GROUP BY cust,ctry,mth

i don't get the required result, i get:
cust   ctry  mth   cost
c001   US  201506  -100
c001   DK  201506  -100
c001   DE  201506  -50
c001   FR  201507  -200
c001   UK  201507   -50

if i do like: 
SELECT cust,mth, MIN(cost)
FROM
(
SELECT distinct cust,ctry,mth,sum(cost)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust,ctry,mth
)
GROUP BY cust,mth

then i get below and i lose 'cntry' column:
cust     mth   cost
c001     201506  -100
c001     201507  -200
```

further if i use INNER JOIN to get 'cntry' column:

```
SELECT cust,mth,ctry,cost FROM mytable AS 'main'
INNER JOIN (
SELECT cust,mth, MIN(cost) as cost1
FROM
(
SELECT distinct cust,ctry,mth,sum(cost)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust,ctry,mth
)
GROUP BY cust,mth ) AS 'sub'
ON main.cust=sub.cust, main.mnth=sub.mnth, main.cost=sub.cost1

then this gives me what is also not desired as 
it is giving me both rows i.e. for US and DK and i need only one here: 
cust   ctry  mth   cost
c001   US  201506  -100
c001   DK  201506  -100
c001   FR  201507  -200
```

I am thankful for any help in writing SQL to achieve the required results as outlined above (section FINAL REQUIRED RESULTS).

thanks for your help./Regards/NOMAN

Comment: Hi nomann, your final result table is wrong (i guess). I think the column entry in `HCtryPP ` in the two last rows should be `FR` and not `DK`, right?

Comment: like so:`cust   ctry  mth   cost  HCostPP HCtryPP HCostAP HCtryAP
c001   US  201506  -100  -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   DK  201506  -100  -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   DE  201506  -50   -100    DK      -200    FR
c001   FR  201507  -200  -200    FR      -200    FR
c001   UK  201507   -50  -200    FR      -200    FR`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing the mistake. I have edited 'final result'

Answer (score 0):

here is the first part, for the PerPeriod results you should you use an over (partion by) construction (which is very well described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html).

```
select 
 t1.cust,
 t1.ctry,
 t1.mth,
 t1.cost,
 (select t3.ctry from mytable t3 order by t3.cost asc limit 1)  HCtryAP,
 min(t2.cost) HCostAP
from mytable t1, mytable t2
group by 1,2,3
order by 3, 4;
```

Comment: with `over (partition by)` you are referring to window functions. Since when does MySQL support them? (And what does that have to do with SAP HANA)